# In my Table Date Order is inserting in wrong way

Tags: c#, oracle

If I insert Start Date = 02-02-2018 & End Date = 05-02-2018.

Currently my data in the table looks like this: (in one time insertion)

```
1. 02-02-2018   05-02-2018
2. 03-02-2018   05-02-2018
3. 04-02-2018   05-02-2018
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
1. 02-02-2018   03-02-2018
2. 03-02-2018   04-02-2018
3. 04-02-2018   05-02-2018
```

Comment: This has actually no C# involved only an insert statement. Try debugging your statements in smaller pieces and inspect the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already looping starting start_date to the end_date. For to_date column, use `start_date + level` :

```
select 
      TO_CHAR((to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (level-1)),'DD-MM-YYYY'),
       TO_CHAR(to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level,'DD-MM-YYYY') ,
       IP_MATERIAL_TYPE,
        IP_BRM_LIST,
        IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION,
        IP_YARD_NO,
        IP_USER_ID,
        IP_USER_IP,
        SYSDATE
         FROM
        dual
        CONNECT BY
        level <= to_date(IP_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1;
```

**Update**: Assuming that the format of column `material` is fixed and is going to be something like `300T`, `500A`, `40F` etc, following query will divide it equally between the number of days.

```
SELECT to_number(regexp_substr('300T', '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE('05-02-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE('02-02-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) || 
       regexp_substr('300T', '[A-Z]') as material
  FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
MATERIAL
--------
100T
```

Calculation using your column names will be like this:

```
to_number(regexp_substr(material, '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE(IP_END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(IP_START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) || regexp_substr(material, '[A-Z]')
```

Comment: Related this, one more question, if i enter Material = 300T then how it will automatically divided according to date which i entered.Like now if i entered 300T then in all 3 inserted dates then in each date its enter 300 T but i want  it should be divided in LIke 300/3 = 100T in each Date. @San

Comment: Updated the answer, check it.